# psql Cannot open extension control file, but the file exists

Tags: django, postgresql, windows, psql

psql command line:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_tgrm;
ERROR:  extension "pg_tgrm" is not available
DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/share/extension/pg_tgrm.control": No such file or directory.
HINT:  The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.
postgres=# yum install postgresql14-contrib
postgres-# CREATE EXTENSION pg_tgrm;
```

The directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtLxY.png)

What am I doing wrong? The file is definately there and I've installed it on another postgresql server just beforehand on the same machine?

This is for a Django project on Windows 11.

Tried to install the pg_tgrm; extension and expected it to work.

Comment: Yum probably doesn't work at all on Windows, and certainly can't be called like that at the psql command line, and if you are using v15 you can't install the module for v14 and expect it to work.

Comment: It looks like the file exists.  Is the directory listing from the same machine which the database software is running on?

Comment: I am really dumb... the extension is pg_trgm, not pg_tgrm.

Comment: Doh, I should have spotted that.  It is hard to spot typos in things which are already unpronounceable.